# How does the sys.objects Catalog View pull from itself?

Tags: sql-server, database-internals, system-tables, sql-server-2017, catalogs

I'm using this stored procedure called [`OBJECT_DEFINITION` as was suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/193512/2639). It's helping me wrap my head around the SQL Server system. However, there is one area that I can't yet figure out. On this one table `sys.objects`, you'll see it pulls from itself.

```
1> SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('sys.objects'))
2> GO

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE VIEW sys.objects AS
    SELECT name, 
      .. stuff.
    FROM sys.objects$
```

Now I'm totally lost how is `sys.objects` selecting from `sys.objects$` what is `sys.objects$`. Thinking there *may* be a table of the same name, I first tried to create a table and a view by the same name, but I can't do that. I get (`f` is the name I picked). You can't do this in any database I've ever used.

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Server x230, Procedure f, Line 1
There is already an object named 'f' in the database.
```

Microsoft docs [`sys.objects` only as a Catalog View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql), it's not listed as a [Base Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables)

The counterpart Catalog View, [`sys.system_objects` pulls from the Base Table `sys.sysschobjs`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/193561/2639), and `OBJECT_DEFINITION` clearly shows that.

My guess is that the SQL here isn't the actually SQL the view is executing, but some kind of comment or description on it: meta-data of sort, and that it's bugged. But, I could be totally off.

Answer (score 3):

`sys.objects` is not a table, it is a system catalog view. The definition shown in the question even shows `Create VIEW ...`. Also, `sys.objects` is not the same thing as `sys.objects$`:

1. You cannot select from `sys.objects$` on a regular connection. You need to be on a DAC connection, though not necessarily in Single-User mode, to `SELECT` from it.
2. They don't have the same number of columns. Just connect to the DAC connection and run the following:

   ```
   SELECT TOP (1) * FROM sys.objects;
   GO
   SELECT TOP (1) * FROM sys.objects$;
   GO
   ```

`sys.objects$` must be an internal catalog view since the underlying fields in `sys.objects` (no trailing `$`) come from these tables: `sysschobjs`, `syssingleobjrefs`, `syspalnames`.

Comment: Well that's definitely juicy. Would you mine taking this speculation over to https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/193574/2639 (my other question) I think you're right and if so this is likely a dupe of that question. I must have skipped the output of these two and just assumed they were same not that they were totally different things. **That's really interesting in and of itself.** If they're different, there is no substance to this question at all.

Comment: Yep, I think that's a great idea. When I post a dupe I own it. Let's dupe this and tackle that one thoroughly. I'll play around with it too and we'll see what we can find. I imagine moving forward a lot of people will be wondering what's going on here.

Comment: They definitely are different. I just updated my answer here, and I think that it adds weight to the idea that the trailing `$` indicates _internal_ system catalog view. I can post an answer on the other one as well. It might be tomorrow, though as I have to call it quits for tonight..